# Suma de cifras de un numero en Javascript

Tags: javascript

como podría obtener  **la suma de cifras de un numero de 2 o más numerales**.

Por ejemplo :

**La suma de cifras de 134 en javascript.**

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con la suma de cifras de 134? explica un poco mas tu pregunta, es demasiado pobre y no muestras un ejemplo de lo que has intentado.

Comment: Hola User, ¿Qué código intentó? por favor añada el código y si tiene problemas o errores , también deberá describirlos.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa:

Para generar un array de caracteres a partir de una cadena puedes utilizar el método `split` pasándole una cadena vacía como argumento.

Para calcular la suma de los caracteres del array puedes utilizar el método `reduce` para ir sumando cada uno de los caracteres convertido a número.

De esta forma la función de suma podría quedarte:

```
function suma(cadena){
  if (!cadena) return 0;
  return cadena.split('').reduce((r, c) => r += parseInt(c), 0);
}
```

Un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
document.getElementById('calcular').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function(){
    var numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = suma(numero);
  }
);

function suma(cadena){
  if (!cadena) return 0;
  return cadena.split('').reduce((r, c) => r += parseInt(c), 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numero"><button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
<br /> <br/>
Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo en una simple línea.

```
(123).toString().split('').reduce((total, actual) => total + +actual, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cómo sumar las cifras de un número, pasos que se siguen en esta respuesta:

1. Convertir en número a cadena.
2. Iterar sobre esa cadena y guardar en un array cada caracter convertido a número
3. Iterar sobre el array de números y sumar cada elemento

```js
var numero = 111111,
    salida = [],
    cadenaNumero = numero.toString();

for (var i = 0, len = cadenaNumero.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    salida.push(+cadenaNumero.charAt(i));
}

console.log(salida);
for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < salida.length; sum += salida[i++]);
console.log(sum);
```

[**Fuente**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7784630)

Otra posibilidad es hacer la suma directamente sin construir el array de dígitos:

```js
var numero = 111111,
    salida = [],
    cadenaNumero = numero.toString();
    suma=0;
for (var i = 0, len = cadenaNumero.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    suma+=(+cadenaNumero.charAt(i));
}

console.log(suma);
```